# Help Identify North Woods "6 Speed" Tandem?

Tags: identify-this-bike, tandems

I came across a North Woods "6 Speed" tandem at a yard sale, and am trying to track down its provenance:

[image: North Woods 6 Speed Tandem]

Unfortunately, the closest I've come across is [Northwoods bicycles](http://www.kent.bike/bikes/northwoods/) (no space), which are [sold at Wal Mart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Kent-Bicycles-Men-s-700C-Northwoods-Hybrid-Bike/28634146).

Is North Woods different from Northwoods? Is there any name for this tandem apart from "6 Speed"?

Comment: I'd guess its the same company as sold at walmart, but the tandem being a bit older than the one they're currently selling.

Comment: The pedals are out of sync.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth I picked up a NORTHWOODS SAFARI on Craigslist about 2 months ago. Mine is also a 3x6. It has a sticker from "Scotts Cyclery"  of Willimantic,Conn.  The sticker is not the typical square type that is on the seattube. This one runs along both seat stays.  A clue that it may have been a low end bike is that it says "quality bicycle" on the headtube badge and was made in Indonesia. I would do a little preemptive maintenance. Most lowend bikes I have worked on seem to have little if any grease in the bottom bracket, headset or wheel bearings. Just use it and enjoy it.